# Left and right action input in Semantic UI

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

How do I attach actions on both sides of an input? My current best attempt is:

```
<form class="ui form">
    <div class="ui left action input">
        <select class="ui compact selection dropdown" name="seats">
            {% for seat in seatOptions %}
            <option value="{{ seat }}">{{ seat }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
        <input id="seatsText" type="text" value="plaats" readonly>
    </div>
    <button class="ui right attached button" type="submit" >aanvragen</button>
</form>
```

This created the required rounding but the button (right action) seems to overlap with the input, as the input's border is still visible around part of the button, as the screenshot shows.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Have you had any luck with this, Steven?

Comment: No. I am no longer using Semantic UI, so I stopped looking for a solution.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @Steven. What are you using now?

Comment: I am now using Bootstrap 4

Answer (score 0):

This is a very very late answer but this is what i got...

```
<div class="ui left action input">
                <div
                  role="listbox"
                  aria-expanded="false"
                  class="ui basic button floating dropdown"
                  tabindex="0"
                >
                  <div
                    aria-atomic="true"
                    aria-live="polite"
                    role="alert"
                    class="divider text"
                  >
                    This Page
                  </div>
                  <i aria-hidden="true" class="dropdown icon"></i>
                  <div class="menu transition">
                    <div
                      style={{ pointerEvents: 'all' }}
                      role="option"
                      aria-checked="true"
                      aria-selected="true"
                      class="active selected item"
                    >
                      <span class="text">This Page</span>
                    </div>
                    <div
                      style={{ pointerEvents: 'all' }}
                      role="option"
                      aria-checked="false"
                      aria-selected="false"
                      class="item"
                    >
                      <span class="text">This Organization</span>
                    </div>
                    <div
                      style={{ pointerEvents: 'all' }}
                      role="option"
                      aria-checked="false"
                      aria-selected="false"
                      class="item"
                    >
                      <span class="text">Entire Site</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." />
              </div>
```

the select is not working but i hope you guys can fix it instead....

And for those who use react this is how to do it:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Dropdown, Input } from 'semantic-ui-react'

const options = [
  { key: 'page', text: 'This Page', value: 'page' },
  { key: 'org', text: 'This Organization', value: 'org' },
  { key: 'site', text: 'Entire Site', value: 'site' },
]

const InputExampleActionDropdown = () => (
  <Input
    action={
      <Dropdown button basic floating options={options} defaultValue='page' />
    }
    actionPosition='left'
    placeholder='Search...'
  />
)

export default InputExampleActionDropdown
```

If it looks so bad and needs css dont forget to import css for html or install the package for react :) Cheers! sorry for not helping much but i hope i help for future searchers